# can we get sorted grep output

Tags: shell, grep, sort

I have same: `1.txt` with `apple` written in it, `2.txt` with `mango` written in it, `3.txt` with `apple` written in it, `4.txt` with `mango` written in it.

`grep -e apple -e mango *.txt` will give result as:

```
1.txt: apple
2.txt: mango
3.txt: apple
4.txt: mango
```

But I need output as:

```
1.txt: apple
3.txt: apple
2.txt: mango
4.txt: mango
```

Is it possible with just `grep` command ? -- without using any other command like sort or so

Comment: No, and even if there was, it would be wrong. Use `sort`.

Comment: No, `grep` does not perform sorting.

Comment: If you want to use only `grep` then you've to do `grep -e apple *.txt; grep -e mango *.txt` manually

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible by only using `grep`. You have to use another tool e.g. `sort`:

```
$ grep -e apple -e mango *.txt | sort -t: -k2,2
1.txt:apple
3.txt:apple
2.txt:mango
4.txt:mango
```